# Multithreading for loop in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, vector

I've got the following code and I'm attempting to add threading so it executes faster but I'm really stumped. I basically want different threads to execute different iterations of the for loop to speed up the process since I'll be pinging a lot of urls. However, I wasn't sure how to do that or if it was possible so I did what is seen below but I get an error at "thread doStuff(exec" right at the exec part that says there is no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list. How can I apply threading to this situation when the value of the parameter for the "exec" function is changing at every iteration of the for loop?

On a side note, if you couldn't tell, I need to put the result of the "exec" function into index i of the vector "work".

EDIT: The last function is supposed to look incomplete because I deleted code that was irrelevant to this problem.

```
vector<string> check(vector<string> url)
{

    vector<string> work;
    for (int i = 0; i < url.size(); i++)
    {
        string ping = "ping ";
        ping.append(url[i]);
        thread doStuff(exec,work.push_back(exec(ping.c_str())));

        cout << work[i] << endl;
    }

    return work;
}
std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    string timeOut = "Request timed out";
    string reply = "Reply from";
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(_popen(cmd, "r"), _pclose);
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
        if (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe.get()) != nullptr)
            result += buffer.data();
    }
return result;
```

Comment: Threading is a wasps nest of potential (and hard to find) bugs if you don't know what you are doing (in most cases; expert only territory). Step 1) learn C++ *really* well. Step 2) learn about synchronization, priority inversion, atomic operations, deadlocking and much more. Step 3) attempt threads.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, Re, "learn C++ _really_ well." And just sweep out King Augeas' stables on your way. Learning all of C++ really well is a monumental task.  One could be qualified to undertake the study of threads after learning a subset of C++ really well. E.g., One need not know how to design a `template` library in order to start learning about threads.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Visual Studio, you might want to consider [parallel_for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728073.aspx).  Also, C++17 introduced the Parallelism TS, which is a work in progress attempt at standardizing parallel algorithms.  [This](https://www.bfilipek.com/2017/08/cpp17-details-parallel.html) blog post gives a nice introduction to what features are available, and how you can try them out today.

Comment: I just tried using parallel_for but when it hits ping.append(domain[i]) it triggers a breakpoint in dbgrptt.cpp.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what caused that breakpoint, but looking at your code, I suspect you will have another problem with using `parallel_for` with your current implementation.  You modify the `work` vector inside the `for` loop.  If you changed that to a `parallel_for` loop, then you would have multiple threads modifying the same vector.  This would need to be synchronized (either with a mutex or a thread-safe vector).

Comment: Can you provide more details about the breakpoint?  I imagine there's a backtrace?

Comment: Oh I see. I wish I could give you more details about the breakpoint but it refuses to tell me because it can't find dbgrptt.cpp. However, I tested to make sure it was a problem with accessing the vector by putting string hi = domain[i] and that caused the same breakpoint. How exactly would I go about adding in the mutex?

Comment: You're probably better off starting with a concurrent vector, like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx).  That said, if you want to use a mutex, here is a simple [tutorial](https://codeyarns.com/2015/01/14/how-to-use-mutex-in-c/) to get you started.

Comment: Why do you use `ping.append()` in the first place?  Can't you just do `string ping = "ping " + url[i];` ?  Does that help?

Comment: I use that to append the url onto the end of the ping command. I get the same error when I try `string ping = "ping " + url[i];`

Comment: I'm going to guess that `url[i]` is not a valid string and that the breakpoint in dbgrptt.cpp is some built-in error handling mechanism within Visual Studio.  Try printing `i` and `url[i]` to see if they are invalid.

Comment: Weird...it says the size of the url vector is 0...I'm not sure why I didn't catch that before.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) 
in for loop

```
auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async,exec,ping.c_str());
work.push_back(handle.get());
```

That should work.

Comment: I get no compilation errors with this but it seems to be running no faster than before.

Comment: Your program with std::thread  (no return) is running faster than before?

Comment: Well I was never able to get std::thread to work but when I use std::async it runs at the same speed.